# DataTemplate Binding depending on property type and with working property Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datatemplate

I check those articles about doing DataTemplate :

- [WPF DataTemplate Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534021/wpf-datatemplate-binding)
- [WPF DataTemplate and Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128897/wpf-datatemplate-and-binding)
- [WPF DataTemplate Textblock binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231838/wpf-datatemplate-textblock-binding)

and thoses about DataTemplate depending on property type :

- [WPF DataTemplate Binding depending on the type of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010511/wpf-datatemplate-binding-depending-on-the-type-of-a-property)
- [Dynamically display a control depending on bound property using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911626/dynamically-display-a-control-depending-on-bound-property-using-wpf)

I'm trying to display a property with different controls depending of the property value. I have this Xaml that is partialy working. I have 2 problems :

1. The property is displaying with the right control, but when I set the value it doesn't go back to the property. Means the "set" of My property is not call (but was before I creates the DataTemplate). I detect that the problem about setting the property is about the ="{Binding Path=.}" but I cannot find the solution to set it otherwise.
2. Also To be able to make it work, I had to "isolate" the Value into a single ViewModel so that the DataTemplate doesn't affect all the other control.

Can you help me find betters solutions to resolves those 2 problems?

Here is the xaml code of my View linked with MyContainerViewModel that has a "ChangingDataType" :

```
<UserControl >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- DataTemplate for strings -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- DataTemplate for bool -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- DataTemplate for Int32 -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=.}" MinWidth="50" Mask="d" MaskType="Numeric" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <!--<Slider Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding Path=.}" Width="100" />-->
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- DataTemplate for decimals -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Decimal}">
        <!-- <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" MinWidth="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />-->
        <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=.}" MinWidth="50" Mask="f" MaskType="Numeric" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- DataTemplate for DateTimes -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=.}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChangingPropery}"/>
</UserControl>
```

**More informations about 2 :**

I wanted to have in a view a label and a property that changes depending of the object. Something like this :

```
<UserControl> 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- ...DataTemplate here... -->
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Allo"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChangingPropery}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

But if I put the DataTemplate on this UserControl resources, it will also affect the Label "allo". So I had to create another view that contains the DataTemplate and MyChangingProperty so that the label Allo would not be affected. But the extra View created just for one property is kind of ugly to me, I'm sure there is a better way to isolate the DataTemplate so it can apply only to one UIControl.

```
<UserControl >
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Allo"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyContainerViewModel}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Note : MyContainerViewModel here is linked with the first view described.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain what problem number 2 is? The scope of a resource in WPF is by design.

Comment: Sure I will add more information on my question for the number 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a `DataTemplateSelector`. You cannot bind primitive types using two way bindings because that would have to be somehow by reference via the `DataTemplate` which I think is not supported by WPF.

The `DataTemplateSelector` now selects the right `DataTemplate` based on the property type and searches for the right `DataTemplate` in the resources by name. This also solves your problem that your `DataTemplates` interacted with the `Label`.

So first you need to define a `DataTemplateSelector` that changes the `DataTemplate` based on the type of the property:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var fe = (FrameworkElement)container;
        var prop = (item as MyViewModelType)?.MyChangingProperty;
        if (prop is string)
            return fe.FindResource("MyStringDT") as DataTemplate;
        else if (prop is bool)
            return fe.FindResource("MyBoolDT") as DataTemplate;
        // More types...
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Then you need to change the `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDTSelector" />
        <!-- DataTemplate for strings -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyStringDT">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyChangingProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- DataTemplate for bool -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyBoolDT">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyChangingProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <!-- More DataTemplates... -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Allo"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyContainerViewModel}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDTSelector}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You can find a bit more information regarding the `DataTemplateSelector` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can of course also set a `DataType` on this new `DataTemplates` but it isn't required because the `x:Key` makes them unique anyway. But if you want then it has to look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyStringDT" DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModelType}">
```

Comment: The xaml DataTemplate under the DataTemplateSelector doesn't work, I have an error "The type MyDataTemplateSelector does not support direct content"

Comment: oops that was my error, works fine. It answers my problem number 2, but MyChangingProperty is still not set when I set the value on the controls. I added ", Mode=TwoWay}" to the content presenter in case but still does not work.

Comment: @Rachel `Mode=TwoWay` on the `ContentPresenter` will not change anything. Which `DataTemplate` did you try? The one for the `String` will only be effective when the `TextBox` loses its focus. (Hint: If you want to apply the back-binding on key press, you have to set another `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the binding: `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyChangingProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.) Please try the bool property with a `CheckBox` too. This should immediately invoke the binding back to the source. If not then please verify if your ViewModel property has a public setter.

Comment: thank for the quick response. I tried the lost focus for the string and the checkBox and it doesn't work. I

Comment: modified the line    '<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyContainerViewModel}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDTSelector}" />'     for     '<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChangingProperty} />'      because I wanted to eliminate the ViewModel. MyChangingProperty is declared like this : 
 '    private object _myChangingProperty;
      public object MyChangingProperty
      {
            get { return _myChangingProperty; }
            set { base.SetValue(ref _myChangingProperty, value); }
        }'

Comment: if I remove the data Template and put a text box instead of a content presenter, my binding on my property works so it is not my property where the problem is located.

Comment: sorry I missed type my comment, you should read `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChangingProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDTSelector}" />`

Comment: @Rachel Your property seems ok at first glance. But I must emphasize that it will definitely not work if you bind `MyChangingProperty` directly to the `ContentPresenter`. It doesn't matter if it is `TwoWay`. You absolutely have to bind the instance of the whole ViewModel. I'm convinced that the solution cannot be that far away. I'm pretty sure that there is only a tiny cause somewhere. So do the following: You can check the back-binding using a few ways. First please verify that you have no binding errors/warnings in the VS output window.

Comment: @Rachel Then you can use a `Converter` for debugging the values as explained [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/) in option 2. Next I would try option 1 of that link on the non-working bindings. Finally you can turn on the tracing for data binding using this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx). You should definitely see where the data binding gets lost. Additionally, just for my understanding, can you please explain what `base.SetValue(ref _myChangingProperty, value);` does? Is it just for calling `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: I replace with the ViewModel instead of the property direcly and used all your debugging Tools. It works now! Weird why it cannot take the property directly. I found at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885757/binding-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-problems] the quote : "The problem is that the two-way binding on the source itself cannot work because it would mean that the whole object (string), (...), must be replaced when user changes the text in the text box. Obviously, this will not work. Two-way binding will work only on a writable property of the bound object." is this why?

Comment: @Rachel Yes, that's exactly the reason behind this problem! If you have a `TwoWay` binding to an int or a string then the data binding engine would need to do a replacement by reference (just like your `base.SetValue(ref ...)` does) which isn't implemented in WPF. This is why you don't see `DataTemplates` on simple/primitive types very often in real applications. Glad I could help you! :-) (If you think that my answer was useful then you can upvote it too.)

Comment: Hehehe I did but I have not enough reputation so my vote is not shown yet hehehe ;) yess you did help a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the previously posted answer is overkill. While a `DateTemplateSelector` is a useful thing to know about, it seems unnecessary to me in this scenario.

> But if I put the DataTemplate on this UserControl resources, it will also affect the Label "allo".

The reason it affects the `Label` object is that the `Label` object is a `ContentControl`, and so does the same template-matching behavior for content types as your own `ContentPresenter` element does. And you've set the content of the `Label` object to a `string` value. But you can put *anything* you want as the content for it.

The way to fix the undesired effect is to intercept that behavior by changing the content from a `string` object to an explicit `TextBlock` (the control in the template that a `string` object normally gets assigned). For example:

```
<UserControl> 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- ...DataTemplate here... -->
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>
            <TextBlock Text="Allo"/>
        </Label>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyChangingPropery}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In that way, you bypass the template-finding behavior (since `TextBlock` doesn't map to any template and can be used directly), and the content for the `Label` will just be the `TextBlock` with the text you want.

This seems like a lot simpler way to fix the issue, than either to create a whole new view or to add a `DataTemplateSelector`.